# RapidXML: Unable to print - Compile-time Error

Tags: c++, xml, printf, cout, rapidxml

I'm trying to print the XML document data in the console using the RapidXML Library in my C++ application.

I'm following the RapidXML Manual [link here](http://rapidxml.sourceforge.net/manual.html), but I got a compile-time error.

**Here is my C++ code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "rapidxml.hpp"
#include "rapidxml_utils.hpp"
#include "rapidxml_print.hpp"

int main() {
    rapidxml::file<> xmlFile("beerJournal.xml");
    rapidxml::xml_document<> doc;
    doc.parse<0>(xmlFile.data());

    std::cout << doc;

    return 0;
}
```

**Here is the error:**

```
rapidxml_print.hpp:115: error: ‘print_children’ was not declared in this scope, and no declarations were found by argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation [-fpermissive]
                 out = print_children(out, node, flags, indent);
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

rapidxml_print.hpp:169: ‘template<class OutIt, class Ch> OutIt rapidxml::internal::print_children(OutIt, const rapidxml::xml_node<Ch>*, int, int)’ declared here, later in the translation unit
         inline OutIt print_children(OutIt out, const xml_node<Ch> *node, int flags, int indent)
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Obs.: I already tried the other two RapidXML print methods described in the manual (link above).

**My setup:**

- Ubuntu 19 x64
- G++ 8.3.0
- RapidXML 1.13
- Qt Creator IDE 4.11.0
- Qt 5.14.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've come across the same issue in the past. The workaround presented in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55408678) has been working great for all of my GCC builds ever since.

To summarize the information of the other answer: It boils down to a name look up change made in GCC 4.7. The workaround consists of creating a file named `rapidxml_ext.hpp` with the content below. Then include `rapidxml_ext.hpp` in your client application/library.

`rapidxml_ext.hpp`

```
#pragma once

#include "rapidxml.hpp"

// Adding declarations to make it compatible with gcc 4.7 and greater
// See https://stackoverflow.com/a/55408678
namespace rapidxml {
    namespace internal {
        template <class OutIt, class Ch>
        inline OutIt print_children(OutIt out, const xml_node<Ch>* node, int flags, int indent);

        template <class OutIt, class Ch>
        inline OutIt print_attributes(OutIt out, const xml_node<Ch>* node, int flags);

        template <class OutIt, class Ch>
        inline OutIt print_data_node(OutIt out, const xml_node<Ch>* node, int flags, int indent);

        template <class OutIt, class Ch>
        inline OutIt print_cdata_node(OutIt out, const xml_node<Ch>* node, int flags, int indent);

        template <class OutIt, class Ch>
        inline OutIt print_element_node(OutIt out, const xml_node<Ch>* node, int flags, int indent);

        template <class OutIt, class Ch>
        inline OutIt print_declaration_node(OutIt out, const xml_node<Ch>* node, int flags, int indent);

        template <class OutIt, class Ch>
        inline OutIt print_comment_node(OutIt out, const xml_node<Ch>* node, int flags, int indent);

        template <class OutIt, class Ch>
        inline OutIt print_doctype_node(OutIt out, const xml_node<Ch>* node, int flags, int indent);

        template <class OutIt, class Ch>
        inline OutIt print_pi_node(OutIt out, const xml_node<Ch>* node, int flags, int indent);
    }
}

#include "rapidxml_print.hpp"
```